# How to highlight a whole word, given its starting index

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string, richtextbox

I've got a RichTextBox, and would like to highlight a whole word, given just its starting index.

I've been able to highlight a word if the starting index and length is known, however in this case I do not know the length of the word. Is it possible to highlight from a starting index to the first occurance of a space?

**UPDATE:**

This is what I've tried so far:

```
resultsRichTextBox.Select(novelOffset - 2, searchString.Length);
```

Unfortunately 'searchstring' is not always the length of the word being searched for, so I need a way of finding the amount of characters from `novelOffset - 2` till the nearest space.

Comment: Can you share some code? I am sure someone will quickly figure out how to find the next empty space.

Comment: Of course, just a sec :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int length = this.richTextBox1.Text.Skip(startIdx)
                              .TakeWhile(x => char.IsLetterOrDigit(x))
                              .Count();
this.richTextBox1.Select(startIdx, length);
this.richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Obviously you can change `char.IsLetterOrDigit` with `x != ' '` or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `String.IndexOf(Char, Int32)`:

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified
>   Unicode character in this string. The search starts at a specified
>   character position.

It will give you the starting and end index of your word. You can then highlight it!

```
int endIndex = resultsRichTextBox.Text.IndexOf(' ', novelOffset - 2);
resultsRichTextBox.Select(novelOffset - 2, (endIndex - (novelOffset - 2)) );
```

You only need to handle what happens if it doesn't find any space after the word. The `endIndex` value will be -1 if that happens. I would simply set the value of `endIndex` to `searchString.Length`.

Comment: For some reason, this is highlighting till the very end of the text box, rather than till the first space.

Comment: Select method takes the length as second parameter, not the end index ;)

Comment: @digEmAll I just noticed haha, I fixed the code I believe, try this :)

Comment: Now it's only highlighting around half of the word :/

Comment: Your code is definitely better if you just look for one character (i.e. the first space), but if you need something more complicated like searching the first non-letter or non-digit character LINQ is definitely easier :)

Comment: @PeekaySwitch - Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: @DotNET Is it a short word? like 3 letters? My length is probably off by 1 I think...

Comment: The word isn't always the same, which is why I couldn't get its length. In most cases it's only selecting the first 2 or 3 characters though.

Comment: @DotNET I was missing Parenthese in the substraction, it should work now.

Comment: +1 for the help. I've adopted @digEmAll 's solution, but thanks for your help too :)

Comment: This code has another problem. If the word that you want to highlight is the last one of the text, IndexOf returns -1 (a real "edge" case eh eh)

Comment: @digEmAll I mentionned that in my answer :D

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't refresh the page :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
int startIndex;

//fill startIndex with the known value

int endIndex = startIndex;

while(rtb.Text.CharAt(endIndex) != ' ' && endIndex < rtb.Text.Length)
{
    endIndex++;
}

rtb.Select(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cfdkx2f.aspx) method given you provide the starting index of the word and look for the SPACE. Find will return you the index of next space and in fact the end of the word (found - 1).

You can then use a select call.